# notifications stop working after starting app via notification

Tags: android, push-notification

**Situation**
The user receives a clickable notification from my app. If it is clicked it launches the app and redirects the user to a specific fragment depending on the data it comes with. This works just fine while the app is running.
Running on Android 7

**Problem**
If the app is not running and is then started by the notification, the start and the redirect work just fine. But if another notification is received while the app is still running, it doesn't work anymore. 
The only function the notification provides is closing the notification drawer. It doesn't even vanish anymore after being clicked like it is supposed to. The onCreate or onResume of the Activity defined in its Intent aren't called either. It just seems to ignore all its settings and close the navigation drawer once its clicked

**Notification Code**

```
private void showNotification(String message, PushEntity.ActionEnum actionEnum, Map<String, String> params) {
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 if (params != null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        startIntent.putExtra(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
 }
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_default_notification)
 .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
 .setContentText(message)
 .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
 .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
 mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
 mNotificationManager.notify(pushNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

**What i tried so far**

- Adding `android:exported="true"` the entry of MainActivity in my AndroidManifest.xml
- Adding the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of and additionally to `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`

**Question**
Can anyone explain to me why this behavior only occurs after the app was started by a notification but not when it already was running?
And does anyone have an idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: " It doesn't even vanish anymore after being clicked like it is supposed to" This is happening only second time?

Comment: @KR_Android only the notification which starts the app works like it should. All following notifications don't have any behavior except for closing the navigation drawer when they are clicked. But this only happens if the app is startet by a notification. If it is run normal all notifications work fine

Comment: I can suggest to things 1. try using new task flag startIntent.setFlags( 
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)  2. builder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: @KR_Android builder.setAutoCancel(true) only makes it vanish. Still doesn't make the intent trigger.
I will try the flag for the intent tho :)

Comment: Both solution are for different problem. :)